# Error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' during grid.FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone where is my code going wrong here? I have wrote the following code under .cs file to get the grid count:

```
    int totalCount = grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep").Controls.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
    {
        CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep").Controls[i];
        HiddenField employeeIDValue = (HiddenField)grid.FindControl("employeeidToRep").Controls[i];
        if (ck.Checked)
        {
            test = employeeIDValue.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

But error display when it come to the line (CheckBox)grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep").Controls[i];

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

Line 80: 
Line 81:             int totalCount = grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep").Controls.Count;
```

Does anyone know what is it going on there?

code in the aspx file:

```
    <tr>   
        <th class="graytext r">Add Reps to Team:</th>
        <td>               
         <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID"
                DataSourceID="dsEmployees" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="1000" EnableViewState="false"
                GridLines="None" CssClass="clGridDirectory">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID='employee_to_rep' Text='<%# Eval("fullname") %>'/> 
                      <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="employeeidToRep" Value='<%# Eval("employeeid") %>'/>
                      <asp:TextBox runat='server' ID='repID' Text='<%# Eval("rep_id") %>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
              </asp:GridView>       
           <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsEmployees" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="app_staff_without_team_select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
          </asp:SqlDataSource>          
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to call FindControl on a `GridViewRow`.

```
grid.Row[0].FindControl("employee_to_rep")
```

for first row.

```
grid.Row[grid.SelectedIndex].FindControl("employee_to_rep")
```

for the currently selected row (if a row is selected)

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking the results of FindControl **before** you access the results:

```
if (grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep") != null)
```

Ideally you would use the **as** operator to cast and then check for null in the next step.

[EDIT]
Based on the other answers...if you are iterating through the gridview rows, you need to skip the header and footer roes and only check in data rows:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in  GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: but the issue here is there have 14 records found and grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep") shouldn't be null

Comment: @Jin Yong-It doesn't matter what SHOULD be, it only matter what IS.  If FindControl returns null, that will cause the error message you're getting.  I'm going to add to my original answer...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really use ASP, but here's my guess:

The documentation at msdn states that

> This method will find a control only
>   if the control is directly contained
>   by the specified container; that is,
>   the method does not search throughout
>   a hierarchy of controls within
>   controls

It could be that housing the `employee_to_rep` control within a `asp:TemplateField` and a `ItemTemplate` (or one of the other container within the `asp:GridView` itself) would prevent the `FindControl` method from working as expected.

However, the documentation finished up by saying

> For information about how to find a
>   control when you do not know its
>   immediate container, see [How to:
>   Access Server Controls by ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the following line of code is searching for any controls inside of your  control.

```
int totalCount = grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep").Controls.Count;
```

You probably need to break apart the above line a little to check which part is the cause of the null reference.
Try :

```
var control = (CheckBox) grid.FindControl("employee_to_rep");
```

I suspect the above will work, however it cannot find any Controls inside of the located control.

You could probably use a recursive approach to solve your issue.
Check this out: http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/27/finding-controls-on-forms.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `GridViewRow`.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grid.Rows)
{
    CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("employee_to_rep");
    HiddenField employeeIDValue = (HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("employeeidToRep");
    if (ck.Checked)
    {
        test = employeeIDValue.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```